# URL shortening (tinyURL, Bit.ly) application for internal deployment (open source or commercial)

Tags: url-shortener

I'm looking for the equivalent of a URL shortening service such as http://bit.ly/ for an internal deployment in our organisation. Anyone know of any open source projects (especially Java ones) or commercial products which I can install internally rather than using an external service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shorty : http://get-shorty.com/

But there's several other url shortener .... most of them are in PHP/Mysql.

Don't know if a Java one exist.

Comment: If you wan't to build you're Shortening service in JAVA : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/02/create-url-shortner-in-java-struts2-hibernate.html

Answer (score 0):

http://monkeytooth.net/2010/12/htaccess-php-how-to-wordpress-slugs/

tells you the core basics of how to achieve the concept with PHP and Htaccess building up from there I can say would solely be on your own. However not all to hard a concept in general to build off of if you know php/mysql. That said your not likely to find anything directly built in JavaScript however using this with JavaScript again wouldn't be all that hard a concept. I say your not likely to find one JS based as you need some type of server-side script to communicate with a DB somewhere, where you have all your short URL identifiers, and JavaScript to my knowledge doesn't support directly at least database connectivity. You can go through any means of AJAX to communicate with a server-side script to then do what you want with the JavaScript though.